# Unresolved reference "design"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading gradle to 4.0, my code stuck compiling with below message.

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:152)
    at ...
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using
Android studio 3.3.2, buildToolsVersion is `28.0.3`

I still trying to googling to solve it, but no progress.  I don't understand why `android.support.design` can't be resolved.

Could you give me any hint for solving it?

[image]

Add build.gralde(project)

```
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

     repositories {
         jcenter()
         google()
         maven {
             url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
         }
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
         classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
         classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6'
         classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.0"
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" } }
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
         google()
     } }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

add build.gralde(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' apply plugin:
 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "io.fogcloud.demo"
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 23
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     lintOptions {
         abortOnError false
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
     compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
         targetCompatibility = '1.8'
     } }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
     implementation 'io.fogcloud.sdk:easylinkv3:0.2.7'
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" }
 repositories {
     mavenCentral() }
```

Comment: How about sharing your **`Build.gradle`**

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: added my build.gralde files.  thanks

Comment: try adding this library     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'

Comment: try this reverse the order of `repositories` in your **`build.gralde(project)`** like  `google() jcenter()`

Comment: @primo even I add after  ` implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'`, result is same.

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried reverse order of repositories, but result is same.  Are repository order is important factor for comile?

Comment: @sungyong also add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` for design support

Comment: add this     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make below changes

Add build.gralde(project)

```
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()

         maven {
             url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
         }
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
         classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
         classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6'
         classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.0"
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" } }
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()

     } }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Now add `dependencies` **`implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`** in your add build.gralde(module)

Answer (score 1):

Change your gradle to 4.10.1
android studio->file->project structure->project->Gradle version